# If dual boot Linux with windows 8 will I still be able to upgrade to windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, dual-boot

So I am planning to dual boot Linux will Windows 8 and am wondering if I will still be able to get the Windows 10 upgrade.

According to this article it sounds like I might not be able to: [Microsoft's Windows 10 secure boot ruling spells trouble for Linux lovers, dual-booters](http://www.techradar.com/us/news/software/operating-systems/microsoft-s-windows-10-secure-boot-ruling-spells-trouble-for-linux-lovers-dual-booters-1289096).

Sounds like I may not be able to dual boot my OS. So does that mean if I was dual booting Linux before the Windows 10 upgrade, and then upgrade to 10 that I won't be able to access my Linux dual boot install?

Comment: This article shows how you can dual boot w/ Windows 10 + Ubuntu: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2015/01/18/tip-for-dual-booting-windows-10-preview-and-linux-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/. As Jander's answer indicates, it's only allowing the manufacturer's the option for UEFI, not that they have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you've linked basically says that new hardware that ships with Windows 10 will no longer need to provide a way to turn off Secure Boot.  In particular:

- Nothing will change for existing hardware.  This rule is only for new hardware.
- Windows 10 itself can work either way.  Microsoft is saying that manufacturers **may** force Secure Boot to be enabled, not that they **must**.  The previous rule was that manufacturers **must not** force Secure Boot.